Telescope find_files sorting
Is there a way to adjust the result sorting in find_files to prioritize file name matches first? Currently, it seems that matches in file names and path names are scored equally. Since I often search for specific files, I sometimes have to scroll quite a bit to find the match I am looking for. I understand that I could theoretically override the file_sorter property with a custom implementation, but I am concerned that parsing the results and extracting file names to score them differently might significantly impact performance. Is there a better or pre-built way to achieve the same result?
I am currently using this config here:
  extensions = {
    fzf = {
      fuzzy = true,
      override_generic_sorter = true,
      override_file_sorter = true,
      case_mode = "smart_case",
    },
  },

